# Как закрыть обход авторизации?

Tags: php

Я уже с ума схожу, как можно обойти авторизацию, я сделал такую авторизацию:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'conect_db.php';

if(strlen($_POST['username'])>0){
if(strlen($_POST['password'])>0){
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']+qwertyuiop);

    $query = "SELECT `username`,`id`
            FROM `users`
            WHERE `username`='{$login}' AND `password`='{$password}'
            LIMIT 1";
    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) {

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ip='$ip' WHERE username='$username' ") or die ("Can't update");
mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET time=NOW() WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'  ") or die ("Can't update");
mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET online='1' WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'  ") or die ("Can't update");

echo "<script>location.href='/game.php?page=pokemons'</script>";

    }
    else {
       echo "<script>alert('Не верный Логин или Пароль'); location.href='/index.php';</script>";
    }
}
}
else{
echo "<script>alert('Вы заполнили не все поля!'); location.href='/index.php';</script>";
}
}
else{
echo "<script>alert('Вы заполнили не все поля!'); location.href='/index.php';</script>";
}

?>
```

А эти хакеры могут зайти под любым логином, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это закрыть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам же уже писали!

```
$password = md5($_POST['password']+qwertyuiop);
```

В этой строчке проблема.
Надо

```
$password = md5($_POST['password'] . 'qwertyuiop');
```

P.S.: вот так нехорошо:

```
$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

При MySQL-ошибке юзер увидит инфу, которую ему видеть не надо. Делайте запись инфы в лог/отправку на e-mail. А юзеру выводите приготовленное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Так у меня оно работает. Когда я ввожу свой логин и пароль правильно меня пускает, когда не правильно не пускает, а эти гады могут зайти под любым логином Т_Т

Comment: @oOKomarOo, вы попробовали скрипт с этой исправленной строчкой?

Comment: Оно теперь вообще не впускает на сайт

Comment: @oOKomarOo, проверьте ваш скрипт регистрации. Данные в БД должны записывать так же, может у вас там осталась такая же старая неправильная строчка.

Comment: Они как то делают через OR тоисть вводят Логин 'OR' пароль пропускают ну или чё то в этом роде.

Comment: @oOKomarOo, так вы последовали моим советам? Если вы не будете отвечать, то вам никто помогать и не будет.

Comment: Да толку от ваших советов?

Comment: @oOKomarOo, может быть, что толку и нету. Но это мы так и не узнаем, если вы ничего не будете отвечать.
__Вы, похоже, не хотите, чтобы вам помогли.__

Answer (score 1):

Соли очень недостаточно! Соль это это - qwertyuiop в ответе [[@Construct](/users/4463/construct)](/users/4463/construct)

Решения которые использую я:

1. mod_rewrite используя `.htaccess` (плюсы: функцией preg_match обычного `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` отвергаем все sql инъекции а конкретно сиволы типа: `=, ', "` и т.д. в GET запросах)
2. Дрючим `POST` запросы... Находим в них конструкции типа SELECT|ALERT|UPDATE|и т.д. Все это происходит с помощью функции foreach() и той же preg_match(). В этом случае функцию preg_match_all() нам нет смысла использовать, так как нам нужно отловить первое вхождение атаки и сделать die('piece of shit you wanted to crack my site? you the loser a dump!'); // Хотя после такогог заявления нужно ожидать худшего!)))
3. пункт 2 применить на `COOKIES` and `SESSIONS`

Теперь от себя:

1. Если Ваш сайт не хранит особо важных финансовых данных типа номера кредитных карт и т.д. он на***й никому ненужен, разве что йунному хацкеру дилетанту!
2. Если Ваш сайт ктото заинтересованый возжелает взломать, он это сделает! Он это не сделает если круглосуточно будет дежурить бригада профи, которая будет отслеживать все и вся!

Да, еще есть XSS(их еще CSS называют) их можно ограничить вылавливанием всевозможных вхождений в БД как `javascript` или `iframe`...

На мое мнение, XSS следует уделить болшьше внимаюя чем SQL Injection, и всегда помнить о том что это внедрение существует!

Короче говоря, читайте литературу, возможности взломов и внедрений, смотрите видео как это делается и ищите выходы из ситуаций...

И как всегда заключительная фраза - Все приходит с опытом. Опыт приходит со временем!

**UPD**: И о соли тоже не стОит забывать! Работает!

Comment: Насчёт "пункт 1 от себя" не согласен.
И ещё, XSS, конечно, следует уделять внимание (а то про него сейчас многие забывают), но SQL Inj тоже надо. Слив БД штука очень не приятная, даже если пароли зашифрованы.

Comment: Я не спорю по поводу п.1. Все зависит от конкурентности!

Comment: Тут не только от важности контента, но и ещё очень от количества пользователей зависит.

Comment: @Construct у меня нет желания холиварить... Описать в принципе все что используется с целью защиты своего WS можно долго. Но поверь, п.1 от себя, норм работает... сайтам уже по многу лет, они в топ 5 в ПС`ах,  и конкуренция большая... Но их до сих пор никто не тронул! Еще раз повторюсь что холивар разводить не люблю, даже нет смысла... У каждого свой опыт, и меры решения определенных задач. В своем ответе я привел конкретные примеры на которые возможно нужно обратить внимание в конкретном вопросе! Я не призываю использывать мои навыки и прочее...